# ¿Cómo hacer un update multiple en una sola instrucción?

Tags: mysql, sql

Si tengo estas 3 instrucciones de update, ¿Cómo puedo crear una sola instrucción update que haga lo msimo?

> update articulosUsuarios set iddet=84735 where
>   iddet=70800 and cotizacion=12504; 
>   update articulosUsuarios set
>   iddet=84734 where iddet=70799 and cotizacion=12504; 
>   update
>   articulosUsuarios set iddet=84753 where iddet=71486 and
>   cotizacion=12504;

Comment: No se puede. Cada update a una tabla es una operacion atomica y no se puede hacer de esa forma.

Comment: Con un `procedimiento almacenado` lo podes hacer

Comment: Gracias lo intente, pero no se pudo, lo que encontre es hacer con un inner join